# Multilevel inheritance/polymorphism and virtual function

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I have a multilevel inheritance (from Ship class -> MedicShip class -> Medic class) with virtual function code as below. I suppose the result should be :

Medic   10
Medic   10

But it generated strange result. On the other hand, if I only use one level inheritance (from Ship class -> Medic class without MedicShip class in between) the result will be OK. Could you find my mistake please? Many thank....

```
#ifndef FLEET_H
#define FLEET_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Ship
{
    public:
        Ship(){};
        ~Ship(){};
        int weight;
        string typeName;

        int getWeight() const;
        virtual string getTypeName() const = 0;
};

class MedicShip: public Ship
{
    public:
        MedicShip(){};
        ~MedicShip(){};
        string getTypeName() const;
};

class Medic: public MedicShip
{
    public:
        Medic();
};

class Fleet
{
    public:
        Fleet(){};
        vector<Ship*> ships;
        vector<Ship*> shipList() const;
};
#endif // FLEET_H



#include "Fleet.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<Ship*> Fleet::shipList() const
{
    return ships;
}

int Ship::getWeight() const
{
    return weight;
}

string Ship::getTypeName() const
{
    return typeName;
}

string MedicShip::getTypeName() const
{
    return typeName;
}

Medic::Medic()
{    
    weight = 10;    
    typeName = "Medic";
}

int main()
{
    Fleet fleet;
    MedicShip newMedic;

    fleet.ships.push_back(&newMedic);
    fleet.ships.push_back(&newMedic);

    for (int j=0; j< fleet.shipList().size(); ++j)
    {
        Ship* s =  fleet.shipList().at(j);
        cout << s->getTypeName() << "\t" << s->getWeight() << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the result was too strange to be revealed here.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created any instances of class `Medic`. Did you mean to say

```
Medic newMedic;
```

instead of

```
MedicShip newMedic;
```

perhaps? So, the `Medic` constructor isn't being called and `weight` and `typeName` aren't being initialized.

Comment: Yes, you are right Gareth. My fault is just copied it from my previous code. Thank you so much. It is worked now...

Answer (score 0):

```
~Ship(){};
```

The first mistake is right here. This destructor should be  `virtual` if you want to delete derived class objects through base class pointer.

Comment: True enough, and important, but the problem *damar* is reporting is unrelated. (And it happens that in this case the error has no adverse consequences, because the derived classes don't and needn't do anything different from the base class on destruction.)

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed it. Thank you so much Nawaz. And Gareth McCaughan in second answer also found my mistake. It should be Medic newMedic instead of MedicShip newMedic. It is worked now.